# Embedding Standard Python 2.7 (MSVCRT9) in a Visual Studio 2013 Application

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, numpy, msvcrt

Is there any possible/safe way to embed the standard Python 2.7 release (which is based on MSVCRT9 – Visual Studio 2008) in a Visual Studio 2013 application (MSVCRT120)?

I know mixing runtimes is fraught with danger and should be avoided if possible, however…

We have a research workflow tool that is built with Visual Studio 2013 (using modern C++ language features that require at least this version) and we want an embedded version of Python in this tool. Our users are still insistent on Python 2.7 support so unfortunately moving to Python 3.5 which is VS2015 (universal runtime) based isn’t possible - http://stevedower.id.au/blog/building-for-python-3-5/

We’ve previously built Python ourselves using the matching VS2013 compiler version and everything works great except for the fact that every module out there for download via pip or resources like http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ are based on the standard MSVCRT9 release and don’t work. As a result it doesn’t seem possible to get a prebuilt package for something critical like numpy for our version of Python.

I really don’t want to take on the burden of having to build every package like numpy, opencv etc. our users need/want from source ourselves with a modern compiler.

We're embedding with Boost Python and I can get things to compile (I've tried building the Boost Python part with both VS2008 and VS2013) but it all explodes in Py_Initialize(). Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Does it have to be CPython? http://ironpython.net/

Comment: I had this exact same issue at my previous job, and we built Python, NumPy and OpenCV ourselves. OpenCV is pretty straightforward, NumPy had some subtleties, but if you can live without a linear algebra library it's pretty straightforward. When I left, I had them convinced that we were going to Python 3.5 for the next release...